# Docopt - Script exits to early

Tags: python, module, blocking, docopt

I recently found this package (docopt), but i cant seem to get it to work properly. Any help what so ever is appreciated.

### The code:

```
"""docopt_demo.

Usage:
  docopt_demo <name>...
  docopt_demo --version

"""
from docopt import docopt

arguments = docopt(__doc__) #   <---- $0

print("WTF!") #                 <---- $1
```

### The output:

```
Usage:
  docopt_demo <name>... 
  docopt_demo --version 
[Finished in 0.052s]
```

### Why?

1. Why doesn't `$1` print?
2. Why does `$0` print?
3. If `$0` is supposed to run last, how do i access the values from `$0`?

Comment: What is the command you're using that generates this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your script is exiting before it gets to the `print` statement. The script is exiting because you have not provided a valid option. Try `python docopt_demo.py --version` or `python docopt_demo.py Oilan`.

Comment: what? why would that make a difference? (fyi, it doesn't, still the same output)

Comment: if you remove the seccond part of the answer, and only keep the edit, i will mark this as accepted :)